# teams - graph api - can't create event with defined organizer / specify channel

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to create an event for a teams. Using the WEB interface, I can create and specify the channel. through the API, there's no channel field.

Also, When I'm specifying an organizer, it's being over writed to some other values.

What I need to do:

1-) create the event and keep the specified organizer

2-) invite all members of the channel (or specify the channel) when creating the event.

I'm following the official 1.0 API:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{my-id}/calendar/events

{
  "subject": "TESTE - New Event - Sala virtual",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does late morning work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2020-04-21T11:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2020-04-21T12:30:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "location":{
      "displayName":"Online"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address":"test@another.com",
        "name": "Test"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
    ,
    {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Teste",
            "address": "group@test.com"
        },
        "type": "required"
    }
  ],
  "onlineMeetingProvider":"teamsForBusiness",
  "isOnlineMeeting": true,
  "organizer":{
        "emailAddress":{
            "name":"Owner",
            "address":"owner@test.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create event API create a new event in a calendar. The calendar can be one for a user or the default calendar of an Office 365 group. So you have to add all members of the group while creating the event

Comment: and why it's overwriting the organizer?

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT event if I create using the default calendar for the group? Why should I need to manually add the members?

Comment: Here group is a o365 group and not a team inside Teams. So it creates an event inside the 0365 group . It does not assign any attendees and also the group becomes the organizer. You can use the endpoint "POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events" . This will make the given user as organizer.